# iAD memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, iad

This code is leaking:

```
   self.adView = ADBannerView* tempAddBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, 416);
self.adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
self.adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
[self.view addSubview:adView];
self.adView.delegate = self;
self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
```

obviously because the adView is never released. Where is the best place to release it?

My attempt to fix it crashes:

```
  ADBannerView* tempAddBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    tempAddBannerView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, 416);
    tempAddBannerView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
    tempAddBannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;


self.adView = tempAddBannerView;
[tempAddBannerView release];
[self.view addSubview:adView];
self.adView.delegate = self;
self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `[self.view addSubview:adView];` retains the `UIView` so you should be safe releasing it **after** that line.